# How to export a data model from Excel

Tags: excel

I have some large tables in the data model of an Excel spreadsheet. Is there a way to export them to say CSV format? Some of the tables are too large to copy to a sheet (> 1 million rows).

I found some ways to do this via Power BI desktop. I hope that there is also a more direct way, directly in Excel.

Alternatively, if Power BI can access Excel's data model, can I also do that myself through some c# code?

Comment: We used to import from a very large csv file by specifing chuks based on line numbers . Perhaps you could export sections.

Comment: @SolarMike If all fails, that is a reasonable approach.